# Why isn't the paragraph tag working?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using Django but for some reason the `<h2>` tag displays `article.title` with no problem but the `<p>` tag won't display anything - even simple text.

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content%}
    <h1>Articles List</h1>
    <div class="articles">
    {% for article in articles %}
        <div class="article">
            <h2><a href="{% url 'articles:detail' slug=article.slug %}">{{ article.title}}</a></h2>
                <p>TEST TEXT</p>
                <p>{{ article.date }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

the `base_layout.html` is

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Carpe Nocturn</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="wrapper">
            <h1><a href="{% url 'articles:list' %}"><img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" alt="Carpe Nocturn" /></a></h1>
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `article.date` exist?

Comment: Yes if I change the <h> tag to article.date it displays it fine. Just not inside the <p> tag.

Comment: also, you have to apply  date filter like `{article.date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }`

Comment: @Mohit if you wish to specify a format that's not the default date settings - yes... However, it should be appearing... Neil - are you really, really sure you 1) didn't typo it, and 2) have checked the returned source to see if there's anything in that `<p>` tag and if there is - check you haven't got some CSS that's marking it non visible?

Comment: @Neil check "page source" - does this `<p>` exist but invisible or does not even exist in generated `html`?

Comment: I've checked the page source and the <p> tag is there with the expected content. It's just not displaying in the browser. This is the article.date as shown in page source  `<p>Aug. 19, 2018, 2:52 a.m.</p>`

Comment: Okay, I'm a dumbass. The problem was the with the CSS. I formatted the body tags but not the paragraph tags, so the font wasn't visible on the background.